# Breqn package is causing \mathcal to not work when used along with \overset

Tags: equations, symbols, breqn

I am trying to place `\mathcal{U}` over and under the symbol `\gtrless` using the following code:

```
$\overset{\mathcal{U}_0}{\underset{\overline{\mathcal{U}_0}}{\gtrless}}$
```

However, what I am seeing is that the `\mathcal` command is ignored when I use it along with the breqn package. Without the breqn package, the code works fine. The command works fine elsewhere in the document. The situation remains same for both `latex` and `pdflatex`. Can anyone give suggestions on what has to be done?

[image]

This is a toy example of my document. I need the breqn package for other equations. Without it, the \mathcal command works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\mathcal{U}_0}{\underset{\overline{\mathcal{U}_0}}{\gtrless}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of a nonworking document?

Comment: Works fine for me, with `amssymb` and `amsmath`.

Comment: When making the toy example, I found that mathcal stops working when using the breqn package. Without it, it works fine. Anyone know a workaround? I need the breqn package for other equations

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question and question title to reflect this new bit of information.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I was about to update the title and question :)

Comment: Friendly advice: Don't use [`breqn`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn); even thorugh it has some very nice features, it is far from finished and now that neither Michael Downes (R.I.P.) or (thereafter) Morten Høgholm are developing it anymore, the package is not likely to improve greatly anytime soon since the code is _very_ complex.

Comment: Note, removing `\overset` from the being of the expression does give `\mathcal` in the underset.  Very strange.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg This must be a bug then. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in `breqn` that doesn't honor the math font choice in the first argument to `\overset` and `\underset`.

Fixing the bug would require deep digging into the very complicated code of `breqn`, which I'm not going to do as I consider `breqn` a nice proof of concept, but nothing really usable at document level.

Here's a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}

\newcommand{\Ugtrless}{%
  \mathrel{\kern0pt\mathop{\gtrless}\limits^{\mathcal{U}_0}_{\overline{\mathcal{U}_0}}}%
}

\begin{document}

This works $X \Ugtrless Y$

\bigskip

This shows the bug in \texttt{breqn}: $\overset{\mathbf{A}}{=}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW I've added this to the breqn bug tracker in my repo of breqn in Github. I'm not 100% sure that's where development is occurring these days, but it's better than nothing `:)`

Comment: @egreg why do you consider breqn to be just a proof of concept? I use that package for my thesis and apart from its bugs I quite like it.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
$\substack{\mathcal{U}_0\\{\textstyle\gtrless}\\{\overline{\mathcal{U}_0}}
}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With ***line breaks***?

Comment: @egreg Yes, with line breaks