# Conflict between breqn and newtxmath packages

Tags: fonts, incompatibility, breqn, newtxmath

I was typesetting a document. I have imported the `breqn` package and everything is working just fine. I decided that I did not like the default Computer Modern math font, so I wanted to change it to something nicer, and through the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/heuristica/) I found Heuristica. All of this is going well until I noticed a problem in how `\implies` is rendered. Here is the output when I type `$ = \implies $`.

[image]

As you can see, the `\implies` symbol looks like an equal sign with a shorter arrow overlaid on top. If I remove either package, the problem disappears. Why and how can I resolve this problem?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[scale=0.85]{heuristica}
\usepackage[heuristica,vvarbb,bigdelims]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\textosf{#1}}

\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
    $ = \implies $
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was rather clear to me that the equal sign `=` was “shifted down” by `breqn`. This observation hinted that the `=` sign was taken from a wrong math font slot, probably. So, I don’t think the conflict is between `breqn` and `heuristica`, but is between `breqn` and `newtxmath`.

I shall first recover the possible wrong mapping of glyph using the original definition of `=` found in [`newtxmath.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newtx/tex/newtxmath.sty):

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{=}{\mathrel}{lettersA}{61}
```

This makes the first `=` in your MWE shifting upward to its correct position.

I shall then provide

```
\edef\Relbar{\mathchar\string"\hexnumber@\symlettersA3D }
```

to fix how `\Relbar` is supposed to behave. Note that `\Relbar` is used to construct many other symbols, e.g., `\Longrightarrow`, `\Longleftarrow`, `\xLeftarrow`, `\xRightarrow` and `\xLeftrightarrow` (the last 3 come from `mathtools`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{heuristica}
\usepackage[heuristica]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\DeclareMathSymbol{=}{\mathrel}{lettersA}{61}
\makeatletter
\edef\Relbar{\mathchar\string"\hexnumber@\symlettersA3D }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    $= \implies$\par
    $\Longrightarrow \, \Longleftarrow$\par
    $\xLeftarrow{abc} \, \xRightarrow{abc} \, \xLeftrightarrow{abc}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Relbar fixed]

---

**Disclaimer**: Although the above solution fixed your problem, it would make `breqn` unable to auto line-break equations at equal signs. However, I’m not a fan of the `breqn` package: It works by *radically changing the way TeX handles math lists*. Currently, it has support for Computer Modern, `mathpazo` and `mathptmx`, but that’s all. There is no support for the new math font packages like `newpxmath` and `newtxmath` (which are the recommended replacements for `mathpazo` and `mathptmx`), and understandably, no support for commercial math font like `mtpro2`.

If your favorite math font doesn’t work with `breqn`, [its documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/breqn/breqn.pdf) states

> **Page 3**: If you find that a particular math font package doesn’t work then please see implementation in `flexisym.dtx` for how to create a support file — it is easier than one might think.

But currently the [`flexisym` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/breqn/flexisym.pdf) is not much documented at all. Unless one has already had ton of experiences with TeX, I doubt any regular user would be able to create such support files on the fly. It took me hours to even locate the bug, and then a few more to find a fix.

Also, you wouldn’t have this problem in the first place if you had not loaded `breqn`. In this regard, I completely agree with @egreg in [this previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248561/164314):

> … I consider `breqn` a nice proof of concept, but nothing really usable at document level.

How hard can it be for anyone to *manually* line-break an equation, knowing that he/she has *full control* of the typographical end result? Who knows what else would be unexpected after `breqn` is loaded. You have so many options provided by `amsmath`:

```
align, align*, gather, gather*, ... ;
split, aligned, gathered, ...
```